# Getting pull access denied when trying to pull emr-6.3.0-latest base image from ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-emr, amazon-ecr

I am following [How to customize Docker images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/EMR-on-EKS-DevelopmentGuide/docker-custom-images-steps.html) and trying to pull base image for emr-6.3.0-latest and try to modify it before I push to ECR. However when I execute below command

```
docker pull 755674844232.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/spark/emr-6.3.0-latest
```

I get error like

```
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for 755674844232.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/spark/emr-6.3.0-latest, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: User: arn:aws:iam::********:user/username is not authorized to perform: ecr:BatchGetImage on resource: arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:755674844232:repository/spark/emr-6.3.0-latest
```

I have also ecr:BatchGetImage policy attached to my user. Not sure what I am missing?

Comment: Would be easier to help with a little more details. For instance, the first thing I'd check is that IAM policy, and whether it is correct. Did you do everything by hand or use CloudFormation, CDK, etc. for IaC?

Comment: My IAM policy looks correct the My user has admin access, and yes running these by cmd not through CloudFormation or sdk. I feel that image is not exist. Could you try to pull the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the base image URI is incorrect on that documentation page that you linked, just as you suspected. I ran into the same problem, as you described, until I found this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0x4DRKmNPfQ), which had a working command:

```
$ aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 711395599931.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
Login Succeeded
$ docker pull 711395599931.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/notebook-spark/emr-6.3.0:latest
latest: Pulling from notebook-spark/emr-6.3.0
321892dd332d: Pull complete 
af6acd606054: Pull complete 
aed277952843: Pull complete 
ba95d0bc7985: Pull complete 
7ef8149b3bb3: Pull complete 
43d41e957447: Pull complete 
b149cafdd5e8: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:4fafa37e98762663b55a53fa7c10ede6c58080ecda5e6749dcb2bcb4b15caa9b
Status: Downloaded newer image for 711395599931.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/notebook-spark/emr-6.3.0:latest
711395599931.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/notebook-spark/emr-6.3.0:latest
```

Maybe they forgot to update the documentation, when the URI was changed. Wouldn't be the first time in the history of IT...

Comment: Thank you so much for finding this for me. Yes it is documentation issue, but why they would have used notebook-spark in url? :)